# How to write this linq query so it isn't so slow

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this SQL statement which is pretty instantaneous when running it:

```
select Distinct statuses.Description, count(*) as count 
from referrals 
inner join statuses on referrals.StatusId = statuses.id
group by statuses.Description
```

But when I run the below linq code with Entity Framework Core, it takes almost 5 minutes to run and there are only 680 rows in the database.

```
var data = context.Referrals
                  .Include(s => s.Status).AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r => r.Status)
                  .Select(g => new StatusCountItem 
                                   { 
                                       Status = g.Key.Description, 
                                       Count = g.Select(r => r).Count() 
                                   }).ToList();
```

Is there a way to write a similar Linq statement that won't take forever to run or do I need to figure out a different way to do what I want?

**EDIT**: when I don't have the `AsEnumerable` I get this error message which is why I added it:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Join(inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: r => EF.Property<int?>(r, "StatusId"),
> innerKeySelector: s => EF.Property<int?>(s, "Id"),
> resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Referral,   Status>(Outer = o, Inner = i))
> .GroupBy(r => r.Inner)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync

Comment: Why are you calling `AsEnumerable` in the middle of the query? That will immediately split your query into a database-ran part, an an in-memory-ran part: everything that happens _after_ the `AsEnumerable` call will take place completely in-memory, after fetching the entire `Referrals` table.

Comment: @julealgon please see my edit as the the error if no AsEnumerable.

Comment: “ g.Select(r => r).Count(“ why not just g.Count?  It is just clearer.

Comment: What is the type of Status field? Is it a navigation property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = context.Referrals
    .GroupBy(r => r.StatusId) // notice the change here, you need to group by the id
    .Select(g => new StatusCountItem()
    {
        Status = g.First().Status.Description,
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Downvoted because it is super ineffective query. Instead of adding just another field to grouping key, you have introduced join to the same result set. It is how EF Core precesses `First()` on grouping items.

Answer (score 1):

Your Sql query is built based on `context.Referrals.Include(s => s.Status).AsEnumerable()`, which is equivalent to:

```
select *
from referrals 
    inner join statuses on referrals.StatusId = statuses.id
```

Note the star, you're querying *every* column. In other words, remove the random `AsEnumerable()` in the middle of your query.

Comment: Also, `.Select(r => r)` is about as useful as you'd expect. Why would you add that?

Comment: please see my edit as the the error if no AsEnumerable.

Answer (score -1):

Use this one, it is simple and will improve query performance.

```
from r in context.Referrals
join s in context.statuses on r.StatusId equals s.Id
select new { s.Description, r.StatusId , S.Id) into result
group result by new { s.Description } into g
select new {
   CompanyName = g.Key.Description,
   Count = g.Count()
}
```

Comment: Using join instead of a navigation property is a deterioration. Also, you can never check if it improves anything, it's just a long shot.

Comment: @GertArnold how can i use a navigation property here?